# Google Images Search Deprecated

Tags: javascript, google-api

I need to integrate Google Images search in my website, but I found out that the API is deprecated.

So basically I want to build an integrated image search (doesn't matter if I use yahoo, google, more?) adds and branding logo's don't matter as long as users can stay on the page and search for images there.

Are there any alternatives? Is it still worth going for the deprecated google API?

This was my example code, that today still works:

```
function getGoogleImages(query, userIp, callback) {
  var url = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=' + query + '&userip=' + userIp + '&callback=?';

  $.getJson(url, function(data) {
    callback(data.responseData.results);
  });
}

  getImages('Horses', 'ip-goes-here', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, results) {
      $('<img />').attr('src', results.unescapedUrl).attr('id', 'img' + i).appendTo('#images');
      $('#img' + i).wrap($('<a />').attr('href', results.unescapedUrl));
    });
  });
```

NOTE:

I am aware of the deprecated API, but custom search is not the thing I want, I want to search on Google Images (http://www.images.google.com) not on MY website.

Comment: I am aware of that, but the custom search API only searches for images on the website I have targeted, not on Google Images so it is completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try azure

https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/5BA839F1-12CE-4CCE-BF57-A49D98D29A44

Seems 5000 hits per month are free

Comment: Good luck finding a working example though. I signed up as developer but still have issues with their example